# iOS AVPlayer with LIVE stream audio - how to graph for visualization?

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, avassetwriter, avplayeritem

I am using avplayer to stream a LIVE audio only url.

I want to create a visualization using this audio.

Similar to this

[image]

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: This one's deprecated, but there are some other alternatives listed here. https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio

Comment: [This](https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension) may help in getting the data out. You can create a visualizer with that.